# Which real numbers have two representations?

Tags: decimal-expansion, real-numbers

Are they only numbers that end with `9999...` and `0000...` after the dot or some other too? If so, can you give an example?

Comment: In decimal base or for other bases?

Comment: Yeah, in decimal base.

Comment: They are the only numbers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any rational number whose decimal expansion terminates, i.e., numbers of the form $$\dfrac{p}{2^m 5^n}$$ where $p,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ can have two different representations. For instance,
$$\dfrac75 = 1.4 = 1.3\bar{9}$$

Comment: Here 'terminates' refers to the same kind of reals I was referring to as ending with `0000...` right?

Comment: @jsoldi:  that is correct.  He is showing which they are.

Comment: @jsoldi Yes, good question. Yes, true.

Comment: Aren't these ALL rational numbers except zero? Since the decimal representation of any given rational number terminates and could be continued by 0000.. or 9999.. (when decrementing the previous digit). Only zero = 0.00.. cannot be decremented.

Answer (score 4):

The only real numbers with two decimal representations have their decimal representations agree up to some point, then one continues with $a999\ldots$ while the other with $b000\ldots$, where the digit $b$ is one more than the digit $a$.  For example,
$$5.5679999\ldots = 5.568000\ldots$$
Another example: $$34199.9999\ldots = 34200.0000\ldots$$